# Placement new overriding existing objects

Tags: c++, placement-new

If I would do placement new on objects that are already created on stack:

```
struct s{
s() { std::cout << "C\n";}
~s() { std::cout << "D\n";}
};

int main() {
        s s1[3];
        for(int i=0; i< 3; ++i)
                s* newS = new (&s1[i]) s();
}
```

I get:

```
C
C
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

So we are not getting destructors for first 3 objects, is that safe? If we just override memory for objects allocated on heap/stack and that objects do not have to free any resources in destructors is that still safe?

Comment: I don't see how this is wrong, you are creating 3 objects on stack, you get constructors for those 3 - then you use placement new to recreate 3 objects again in the same location so you get your 3 constructors again and at the end you get 3 destructors. Are you expecting something different?

Comment: Very unsafe - the destructors being called are for the original 3 objects not for the 3 created with placement new.  This may cause surprise.

Comment: There is no memory leak here, the objects have been overridden.

Answer (score 4):

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/no1ZPHkB35JcYyZv)

Your output is not unexpected - [*placement `new`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) does not invoke the destructor of any potential object stored in the memory location you're accessing. You need to [explictly invoke the destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) of any object that occupies the memory location you're trying to use in order to use *placement `new`* safely.

```
struct s
{
    s()
    {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }
    ~s()
    {
        std::cout << "D\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Three 's' instances are constructed here.
    s s1[3];

    // (!) You need to explicitly destroy the existing
    // instances here.
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        s1[i].~s();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        // Three 's' instances are constructed here.
        s* newS = new(&s1[i]) s();
    }

    // Three 's' instances are destroyed here.
}
```

---

Output:

```
C
C
C
D
D
D
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

Comment: And calling destructors explicitly is a good thing? consider this {
  Class foo;
  foo.~Class();
} calls the destructor twice

Comment: @SamerTufail: it's not a "good or bad" thing - it's a **necessary** thing when working with placement new. Your example does not use placement new, so there's no need of calling destructors explicitly.

Comment: I know. Point being he you are destroying objects allocated on stack explicitly and recreating them using placement new. It would be better to allocate a predetermined size on heap first and use that to create the objects which is how memory pools work rather than using it in this contrived way.