# Can we always use placement-new on same type or it may result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, placement-new

From what I get, it should normally be correct to use a placement-new for reconstructing a type like this:

```
A a;
auto aptr = new(&a) A();
```

So I decided to try it with a class member like this:

```
struct PackedTest {
    char a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    void setb() {
        new(&b) int(5);
    }
};

int main() {
    PackedTest p;
    std::cout << sizeof(p) << "\n";
    std::cout << p.b << "\n";
    p.setb();
    std::cout << p.b << "\n";
}
```

and everything seems fine. But then I thought if we can always do the same with struct members? Let's assume that we have following packed struct:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) PackedTest {
    char a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    void setb() {
        new(&b) int(5);
    }
};
```

Is this code still valid or it is undefined behavior? Because in previous case, alignment of `b` was equal to alignment of `int`, so placement-new should be fine. But in this new struct, alignment of `b` is `1` which is less than alignment requirement `int`.

Should I **always** add `alignas(T)` like:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) PackedTest {
    char a = 0;
    alignas(int) int b = 0;
    void setb() {
        new(&b) int(5);
    }
};
```

as a rule of thumb for any variable that will be used as buffer for placement-new (though it seem this `alignas` is somehow affects whole structure, not just `b`)?

Comment: Placement new should only be used on memory that doesn't already contain an object.  I'm not sure what the spec says about it, but I strongly suspect what you're doing is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom I really didn't see this requirement that you mention anywhere. I just know that memory should have correct alignment for our required type.

Comment: For the delete there's [c++ - Placement new overriding existing objects - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287330/placement-new-overriding-existing-objects) (but it doesn't say it's undefined behavior?)

Comment: @MarkRansom I just remembered that I have seen placement new on memory containign object in cppref at least. in this example:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder

Comment: There's [c++ - Do I really have to worry about alignment when using placement new operator? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781724/do-i-really-have-to-worry-about-alignment-when-using-placement-new-operator) which seems to apply to the case here...

Comment: It results in undefined behaviour. `std::vector<100> a;
auto* aptr = new(&a) std::vector(100);`. The least trouble is memory leak.

Comment: @S.M. you need to call destructor in your case manually. so it will be something like this:`std::vector<X> a(5); a.~vector<X>(); auto* aptr = new(&a) std::vector<X>(5);` (though not sure if it is still valid). But my question is more regarding alignment requirement. should I always add `alignas` to storage to make sure everything will be valid?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't say anything about the meaning or effects of `__attribute__((packed))`. You are in the land of implementation-defined behavior. Consult the documentation for the particular implementation you are using.

Comment: @Afshin The examples in your question do not call destructors.

Comment: As already mentioned above it is more about `packed` attribute than placement new. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568441) it is discussed even `*(&b) = 5` cause segmentation fault on some system. Also in the linked answer they say gcc 9 and above should have `-Waddress-of-packed-member` warning enabled by default.